Doesn't swc-loader have class support?
I'm migrating an old React codebase from Webpack to rspack for better performance. In the migration, I'm changing the loader from Bable to swc-loader. But the swc-loader throws an error on handling class-based components saying super is in invalid keyword.
Note: I've shared code from a package called CKEditor which we've in our src directory with some modifications. But I also use some old components which class-based implementation.
ERROR in ./src/vendors/ckeditor5/build/ckeditor.js
  × Module parse failed:
  ╰─▶   × JavaScript parsing error: Invalid access to super
             ╭─[16130:53]
       16128 │                                 return [
       16129 │                                     5,
       16130 │                                     _ts_values(super.getRanges())
             ·                                                      ─────────
       16131 │                                 ];
       16132 │                             case 1:
             ╰────
      
  help: 
        File was processed with these loaders:
         * builtin:swc-loader??ruleSet[1].rules[1].use[0]
        You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.


Doesn't swc-loader has support for class-based component built-in?
If not what could I do to add it or is there any workaround for this issue?
Thanks in advance...

The error message doesn't say "invalid keyword", it says invalid access.

I've updated the code and shared the error message thrown from a package. The file that throws the error is a minified file.
But I've some old components that use class-based implementation. I'm afraid that also will throw the error since it also uses the super keyword

Thank you for sharing the error, please may you share a [mre] of the code used?
